# Error:d1 was not declared in this scope; How to fix this error in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;
class cowboy
{

public:
    int life;
    int player;
    int maxatk;
    int minatk;
    int type;
    cowboy()
           {


           }
    cowboy(int v, int am, int an, int t)//it is an constructor which is a function that will let us assign the four variables in a single instruction when the cowboys is created
       {
        life=v;
        maxatk=am;
        minatk=an;
        type=t;

        }

};
void duel();



int main()
{
    duel d1;
    d1.mainmenu();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
class duel
{

public:
    duel()
    {


    }
    void mainmenu()
    {
        int choice;
        do
        {
            cout<<"main menu\n";
            cout<<"1-play\n";
            cout<<"2-history\n";
            cout<<"3-exit\n";
            cin>>choice;
            if(choice==1)
            {

            }
            else if(choice==2)
            {

            }
        }
            while (choice!=3)


            }


void selectcowboy()
{

     cout<<"select your cowboy\n";
     cout<<"1-Basic\n";
     cout<<"2-resistence\n";
     cout<<"3-fast cowboy\n";
     cout<<"choose";
     int choice;
     cin>>choice;
     cowboy player;
     cowboy machine;
     if(choice==1)
     {
         player.life=30;
         player.maxatk=15;
         player.minatk=8;
         player.player=1;
         player.type=1;

     }
     else if(choice==2)
     {
         player.life=50;
         player.maxatk=15;
         player.minatk=8;
         player.player=1;
         player.type=2;

     }
    else if(choice==3)
    {
        player.life=28;
        player.maxatk=9;
        player.minatk=5;
        player.player=1;
        player.type=3;

    }
    int rival=rand()%3+1;
    if(rival==1)
{
    machine.life=30;
    machine.maxatk=15;
    machine.minatk=8;
    machine.player=1;
    machine.type=1;

}
else if(rival==2)

{

    machine.life=50;


machine.maxatk=15;
machine.minatk=8;
machine.player=1;
machine.type=2;
}
else if(rival==3)
{

    machine.life=28;
    machine.maxatk=9;
    machine.minatk=5;
    machine.player=1;
    machine.type=3;

}
else
{
    cout<<"error"<<choice<<endl;

}
//incia el dueolo
cout<<"\n preparing duel\n";
cout<<"player life"<<player.life<<"machine life"<<endl;
cout<<"duel starts now"<<endl;
bool s=true;//bool variable is used to find whether it is your turn or not
while(true)
{
    if(s==true)
    {
        player.minatk+player.minatk        ;


    }
    else
    {
        machine.minatk+machine.minatk;


    }
    cout<<"player's remaining life"<<player.life<<"\n";
    cout<<"machine's remaining life"<<machine.life<<"\n";
    if(player.life<=0)
    {


    }
    else if(machine.life<=0)
    {

    }
    if(s==true)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

}
    }
    void story()
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: Try moving `int main() { ...}` to the bottom of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare a variable of class `duel` before introduing it. So you need to move the `main()` method below the `duel` class definition:

```
class duel
{
...
};

int main()
{
   duel d1;
   ...
}
```

By the way, it would be better to keep your classes in separate files, i.e., create `Duel.h` and `Duel.cpp` files and move the implementation of `Duel` class to them. Then `#include "Duel.h" in your main c++ file.

Answer (score 0):

Your main function cannot find a declaration for the object `duel`.

To fix this you have to move your `main()` function at the bottom of your file (or at least after every class, struct or function has already been defined)

```
class duel
{
     //...
}

int main()
{
    duel d1; 
    d1.mainmenu(); // this works
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Second option doesn't work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b2736c71b02d6c6